# can't connect to RDS with EC2-SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Suddenly My sequel pro does not work well.

I get sequel connect RDS via EC2.

The setting seems to be correct.

I have chosen correct pem fale to connect SSH.

I don't know why "No more authentication methods to try."happen

[image]

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-23-214-216-2.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to connect via SSH? Are you using the EC2 instance as a Jump Box to access a private database?

Comment: Your log output does not seem to show you offering use of `~/Downloads/stacktest.pem` like you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon RDS is a managed database service. No access is provided to the underlying infrastructure.

If you wish to connect to an Amazon RDS database, you will need to connect your SQL Client directly to the database via its designated port (eg MySQL port 3306). It is *not* possible to connect via SSH.

See: [Connecting to an Amazon RDS DB instance - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html)

Comment: I don't understand the characters, but I assume OP is trying to tunnel through an EC2 Instance to the database port.